# How can I ask the OS to run each thread on another core?-Linux OS

Tags: linux, multithreading

I am trying to run a multiple threads program on a 4 core processor, and I want each thread to run on a different core.

How can I do that? Because right now I see that they all running on the same core.

(I'm using Linux OS and my code was wrriten on c.)

Comment: The OS should automatically allocate threads to get the best performance. If more than one thread is doing significant work, then the threads should get scheduled across all available cores, unless told otherwise. Can you determine how much CPU usage the threads cause on each core etc?

Comment: Are you sure your program actually has multiple threads?  As Spectre said the threads should automatically get allocated to different cores.

Answer (score 4):

Process schedulers make processes have  an [affinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity) towards a specific CPU. You've already loaded a bunch of stuff into cache, you may as well keep using this 'hot' cache.

You may be getting all the threads on this same core, since you already have the program loaded here.

I did find this: [pthread_setaffinity_np](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html). It seems clumsy, but i hope it's of some use.